# Missing methods in NerdDinner with Entity Framework setup

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, nerddinner

I am starting to learn the ASP.Net MVC framework with the help of the "Professional ASP.Net MVC 2" book from Wrox press. It introduces the framework by example of building the NerdDinner web application. It was smooth sailing at the beginning, I did every step it has described with setting up the DB tables and the Entity Framework mapping.

Now I got to the part where it shows me how to create the repository class for this app. And this is where I'm stuck. It gives the code for the `Add` method as follows:

```
public void Add(Dinner dinner) {
    entities.Dinners.AddObject(dinner);
}
```

The problem is that I don't have the `AddObject` method, or any method that contains the words Add or Insert or any variation on that theme. Same problem with Delete. At first I thought the book might have been assuming .Net 4 and VS 2010, but I checked the book into section again, and it explicitly says that VS 2008 (all editions) and .Net 3.5 are supported. I have MVC 2.0 installed using the MS Web Installer, and MS SQL Server Express 2008 R2 as the back-end.

What could I be missing? I hope it's just some reference that they've forgot to mention in the book.

Answer (score 0):

[AddObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487277.aspx) is a method on the [`ObjectSet<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx) class defined in the `System.Data.Entity` assembly.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that MSDN page too, but it doesn't make sense. It claims that the method is .Net 4 only. Is the book wrong in claiming VS 2008 support then?